# C++ Template Template Instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have the following encapsulation code for variadic parameter packs.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct pack
{
};

template <template <typename... Args> class ENCAP, typename... Args>
struct encapsulate_arguments
{
    typedef pack<ENCAP<Args>...> type;
};

template <template <typename... Args> class ENCAP, typename... Args>
struct encapsulate_arguments<ENCAP, pack<Args...>>
{
    typedef pack<ENCAP<Args>...> type;
};

template <typename L>   
struct Master
{
    template <typename T>
    struct Slave
    {
        typedef T type; 
    };
};
```

This works fine for encapsulating variadic packs such as:

```
typedef encapsulate_arguments<Master<float>::Slave, double, int>::type foo;
```

or

```
typedef encapsulate_arguments<Master<float>::Slave, pack<double, int>>::type foo;
```

or

```
typedef encapsulate_arguments<std::vector, pack<double, int>>::type foo;
```

*where it is not dependent on another template parameter* - resulting in the following being defined :

```
pack<Master<float>::Slave<double>, Master<float>::Slave<int>>
```

or

```
pack<std::vector<double>, std::vector<int>>
```

The problem is that if I want to make the encapsulation template parameter ENCAP type dependent I can't get it to compile:

```
template <typename L>   
struct Other
{
// ARGGH!!!
//  typedef encapsulate_arguments<Master<L>::Slave, pack<double, int>>::type EmbeddedType;
};
```

http://ideone.com/ZwfVaU

Is this even possible and / or how can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `typename` and a `template`:

```c++
typedef typename encapsulate_arguments<
//      ^^^^^^^^
    Master<L>::template Slave, pack<double, int>
//             ^^^^^^^^
>::type EmbeddedType;
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def1441199fdd2c6)**